# Setting endpoints in pub&sub in rclpy ROS2

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, data-distribution-service, ros2

I am  trying to run the [demo](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Python-Programming) example from rclpy client library .

My question is I am able to run the publisher and subriber example from the client library on the same machine.
But Now I want to run these two on different machine for example I want to run mz publisher on my windows host machine and the listener on LInux vitrual machine 
Where can I set the endpoints for pu&b&sub in rclpy lib so that my publisher on windows can send data to the listener running on LInux VM.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite simple to run nodes on different machines using ROS2. All you have to ensure is that you are connected to the same network. You can get a detailed explanation in the [following thread](https://discourse.ros.org/t/how-to-run-example-talker-listener-on-2-machines-with-different-ipaddr/2106/2).